# php pagination for a variable contain array

Tags: php

i want to display 2 array record per pages.Please help with the simple pagination.when user clicks on next page next 2 array record should display.

```
[dotdList] => Array
        (
[0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Just at Rs. 799
                    [description] => Ambrane
                 )
[1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Flat Rs.249
                    [description] => Sarees & more
                )

[2] => Array
                (
                    [title] =>  Extra 10% off
                    [description] => Routers
                )
[3] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Just Rs.549
                    [description] => From Nova
                )
)
```

This is what i have tried and the array contains around 1500 Records.Pagination is not looking good. Its giving very big result and if i wanna hide some of the numbers in between just to reduce its width. or may be next option or dot in between. I wanna display minimum of 15-20 records per pages.

```
<?phpnamespace clusterdev;class Flipkart{private $affiliateId;private $token;private $response_type;private $api_base = 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/';private $verify_ssl   = false;function __construct($affiliateId, $token, $response_type="json")
{
    $this->affiliateId = $affiliateId;
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->response_type = $response_type;
    $this->api_base.= $this->affiliateId.'.'.$this->response_type;
}

public function api_home(){
    return $this->sendRequest($this->api_base);
}

public function call_url($url){
    return $this->sendRequest($url);
}

private function sendRequest($url, $timeout=30){

    if (function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_setopt')){

        $headers = array(
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Fk-Affiliate-Id: '.$this->affiliateId,
            'Fk-Affiliate-Token: '.$this->token
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-ClusterDev-Flipkart/0.1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->verify_ssl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result ? $result : false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }        }}$flipkart = new \clusterdev\Flipkart("shopXXonh", "4e88c0b31f3b45XXXa746fcfdae39af", "json");$alloffers_url ='https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/offers/v1/all/json';$url = isset($_GET['url'])?$_GET['url']:false;if($url){$hidden = isset($_GET['hidden'])?false:true;$details = $flipkart->call_url($url);if(!$details){echo 'Error: Could not retrieve products list.';exit();
}
$details = json_decode($details, TRUE);}$offer = isset($_GET['offer'])?$_GET['offer']:false;if($offer){if($offer == 'alloffers'){
$details = $flipkart->call_url($alloffers_url);if(!$details)
    {
        echo 'Error: Could not retrieve Top Offers.';
        exit();
    }

    $details = json_decode($details, TRUE);

    $list = $details['allOffersList'];

    echo '<h2> All Offers</h2>';

    echo "<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=1 style='text-align:center'>";
    $count = 0;
    $end = 1;if(count($list) > 0){
        //foreach ($list as $item)
        //{
        $count++;
        /*echo"<pre/>";
        print_r($list);
        echo"<pre/>";*/
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] > 0 ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;      

function display($list, $page = 1) 
{
$start = ($page - 1) * 2;
$item = array_slice($list, $start, 2);
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
/*echo"<pre/>";
print_r($list);
echo"<pre/>";*/
    echo $val['title'] . '<br/>';
    echo $val['description'] . '<br/>';
    echo "<br>";}}$len = count($list);echo $len."<br/>";$pages = ceil($len /2);echo $pages;if ($page > $pages or $page < 1) {echo 'page not found';}else{display($list, $page);
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $pages ; $i++)
{
    $current = ($i == $page) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    if ($current) {
        echo '<b>' . $i . '</b>';
    }else
    {?><a href="http://localhost/flipkart-api/fkt_offer.php?offer=alloffers&page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a><?php }}}}if($count==0){echo'<tr><td>No Top Offers returned.</td><tr>';}exit();}else{
    echo 'Error: Invalid offer type.';
    exit();}}echo '<h2> <a href="?offer=alloffers">All Offers</a></h2><br><br>';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let me explain you logic:**

1) Take count of array into a variable.

2) Count number of page from above variable.

3) Show pagination href links below the records.

4) If the page number is invalid, show page not found error.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  array('title' => 'Just at Rs. 799', 'description' => 'Ambrane'), 
  array('title' => 'Flat Rs.249', 'description' => 'Sarees & more'), 
  array('title' => ' Extra 10% off', 'description' => 'Routers'), 
  array('title' => 'Just Rs.549', 'description' => 'From Nova')
);
// display
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] > 0 ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
function display($arr, $page = 1) {
    $start = ($page - 1) * 2;
    $arr = array_slice($arr, $start, 2);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        echo $val['title'] . '<br/>';
        echo $val['description'] . '<br/>';
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
$len = count($arr);
$pages = ceil($len / 2);
if ($page > $pages or $page < 1) {
    echo 'page not found';
}
else {
    display($arr, $page);
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $pages ; $i++) {
        $current = ($i == $page) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        if ($current) {
            echo '<b>' . $i . '</b>';
        }
        else {
            ?>
<a href="?page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
<?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RashmiSonke, I would definitely. But, you first try yourself at your best. Its not too tough. I have already explained logic.

Comment: definitely...I will show you the code as well..I am getting the result as well.

Comment: please check the code i have mention above. the pagination is giving me a very big row with numbers. how can i make it small or may be i can add some next or previous tag on this. same array result is displaying on every page.

Comment: i just got the result correctly..Only i want to add next and previous tag to pagination.